# How to query by a record saved as Reference with Skygear in Javascript

Tags: javascript, skygear

I am trying to create a one-to-one relationship between two record types using skygear-SDK-JS https://github.com/SkygearIO/skygear-SDK-JS, and followed the guide https://docs.skygear.io/guides/cloud-db/data-types/js/ to save the record with `Reference`. As written in the guide, Skygear server will create the foreign key constraint for me.

However, I can't find how to call the `skygear.query` API using `Reference`.

For example, with the following code copied from the guide.

```
const note1 = new Note({
  heading: 'Specification',
  content: 'This is first section',
});
const note2 = new Note({
  heading: 'Specification page 2',
  content: 'This is second section',
});
note1.nextPage = new skygear.Reference(note2);
skygear.publicDB.save([note2, note1]);
```

Now I want to find the `Note` that the `nextPage` which the `heading` is `Specification page 2`, how should I construct the query object?

Answer (score 0):

To query `Skygear` record with reference, simply construct a query object that has an `equalTo` predicate on the reference column as follow:

```
let query = new skygear.Query(Note);
query.equalTo('nextPage', new skygear.Reference({
  id: 'note/uuid-of-note2'
}));
skygear.publicDB.query(query).then((notes) => {
  console.log(notes[0]); // You should got note1
});
```

In your usecase, following code should works.

```
let query = new skygear.Query(Note);
query.equalTo('heading', 'Specification page 2');
skygear.publicDB.query(query).then((notes) => {
  let refQuery = new skygear.Query(Note);
  refQuery.equalTo('nextPage', new skygear.Reference(notes[0]));
  skygear.publicDB.query(refQuery).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```